# How to log multiple characters in charCodeAt

Tags: javascript

For the code below it will obviously only log "m" in the word "man" because of the "0". How do I log all three letters?

```
var userChoice = prompt("let me encode something!");
var userChoice = (userChoice.charCodeAt(0) );
console.log (userChoice);
```

Comment: By looping over the letters?

Answer (score 0):

Use plain loop(for backward compatible with older version of browsers) to loop through all characters in userChoice

```
var userChoice = prompt("let me encode something!");
for (var i = 0; i < userChoice.length; i++) {
  console.log (userChoice.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how bout this?

```
var userChoice = prompt("let me encode something!");
for (i = 0; i < userChoice.length; i++) {
    console.log(userChoice.charAt(i));
}


var userChoice = prompt("let me encode something!");
for (i = 0; i < userChoice.length; i++) {
    console.log(userChoice.charCodeAt(i));
}
```